# PHP - Extract first 3 elements of an array -> Shuffle it -> and add them back to the orig. array

Tags: php, arrays, slider, extract, splice

is it possible to "extract" the first 3 elements of an array, then shuffle this 3 elements and add them back to the array?

It's a slider and the first 3 slides should be random displayed on every pageload ...

Could someone help?

```
 public function shuffle( $data ) {

    // Return early there are no items to shuffle.
    if ( ! is_array( $data['slider'] ) ) {
        return $data;
    }

    // Prepare variables.
    $random = array();
    $keys   = array_keys( $data['slider'] );

    // Shuffle the keys and loop through them to create a new, randomized array of images.
    shuffle( $keys );
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        $random[$key] = $data['slider'][$key];
    }

    // Return the randomized image array.
    $data['slider'] = $random;
    return $data;

}
```

/* ----------------------- UPDATE ----------------------- */

This is how it works for me, but why? Im relative new to php ;D

```
public function shuffle($data) {

    // Return early there are no items to shuffle.
    if (!is_array($data['slider'])) {
        return $data;
    }

    $sliced_array = array_slice($data["slider"], 0, 3, TRUE);
    // Shuffle the keys and loop through them to create a new, randomized array of images.
    shuffle($sliced_array);


    $data['slider'] = $sliced_array + array_slice($data["slider"], 0);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, really!! 
I've added my "solution" that works for the slider, but i'm not sure why it's working!

Is this :
$sliced_array = array_slice($data["slider"], 0, 3, TRUE);
the same sliced array :
$data['slider'] = $sliced_array + array_slice($data["slider"], 0);

BR, Patrick

Comment: You are making one-too-many `array_slice()` calls.  Otherwise, you have mostly adopted my posted answer.  If you would like to accept my answer, you can mark it with the green tick.

Comment: You have added some unnecessary syntax to my answer.  See my comments in this demo: https://3v4l.org/jCmfr

Comment: why have you accepted the foreach looping version after showing the more concise array union method in your question?  Did my answer not sufficiently explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You were on right track. With a few tweaks it worked well.

Code:

```
public function shuffling($data) {

    // Return early there are no items to shuffle.
    if (!is_array($data['slider'])) {
        return $data;
    }

    $sliced_array = array_slice($data["slider"], 0, 3, TRUE);
    // Shuffle the keys and loop through them to create a new, randomized array of images.
    shuffle($sliced_array);

    foreach ($sliced_array as $key => $value) {
        $data['slider'][$key] = $value;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I've tried with sample array like:

```
shuffling(["slider" => [
        0 => "A",
        1 => "B",
        2 => "C",
        3 => "D",
        4 => "E",
]]);
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
    [slider] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => C
            [2] => A
            [3] => D
            [4] => E
        )

)
```

Note: `shuffle` is already function defined in php. That's why I've changed name to `shuffling`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

//get 3 first elements and remove 3 first elements from main array
$remains = array_splice($data,3);

//shuffle 3 elements
shuffle($data);

//join everything back
$data = array_merge(array_values($data), array_values($remains));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/rYfV2

```
public function shuffler($data) {

    // Return early there are no items to shuffle.
    if (!is_array($data['slider'])) {
        return $data;
    }

    // Generate a copy of first three elements.
    $first = array_slice($data['slider'], 0, 3);

    // Shuffle first three elements.
    shuffle($first);

    // Overwrite original first three elements.
    $data['slider'] = array_replace($data['slider'], $first);
    // $data['slider'] = $first + $data['slider'];  // function-less alternative

    // Return the randomized image array.
    return $data;

}
```

`array_replace()` avoids doing the replacement process in a more verbose / iterated fashion. It also avoids handling the full array, when you only wish to handle the first three elements.  At no point is it necessary to call `array_values()`.

You can also use the union operator instead of `array_replace()` -- see my commented line of code under the `array_replace()` line.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mgsru))

From [PHP Documentation Array Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.